# IE8 change event listener on textarea not working

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a page where I generate textareas via AJAX and fire events if those textareas are changed.  This works great on IE9+ and other browsers such as Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc.  The problem is IE8 and under.  They don't fire the change event.  The code is:

Textarea looks like:

```
<textarea name="answer8158" id="answer8158"></textarea>
```

Javascript looks like:

```
document.observe('change', function(e, el) {
    if (el = e.findElement('textarea')) {
        //Do Something
    }
});
```

Is there a workaround to make the change event work?  I would be fine with PrototypeJS or pure javascript solution.

Thanks.

Comment: The part `el = e.findElement` is a paste error, right?

Comment: MSIE versions... gotta love'em. Maybe you can catch the `blur` event? It should give the same result as most of the time, `change` is fired when the input-like element loses the focus, instead of being fired each time a key is pressed that alters the element's content/attributes.

Comment: I did try blur as well, but that gives the same result.  @RobG No its not a paste error, that is how PrototypeJS works.

Comment: Ok, you can use `if ((el = e.findElement(…)))` to make it clearer that assignment is intended.

Comment: @StockOverflaw—the onchange event for textarea elements is perfectly functional in IE 6+ (and earlier), perhaps you should change your comment.

Comment: @RobG I can't edit anymore, only delete, and it seems that it's _still and again_ a buggy MSIE interpretation of some JS (according to the author's solution below). That post wasn't that much pointless after all ;)

Comment: @StockOverflaw—the OP hasn't proven to me that the error is IE's fault. My testing in IE 6 doesn't show any errors, so it's not related to the change event as far as I can tell. Guess we'll never know now.

Comment: The main browser I am using is IE8 with Prototype 1.7.  I did try Prototype 1.7.1, but didn't have any luck either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to go back to hard coding the onchange events in the AJAX.  Unfortunately the document observe (blur/change) doesn't work for IE8 and under.  Not how I like to write code, but is the only solution I have found.

Comment: I find that very strange, Prototype.js has been around longer than jQuery and is reasonably widely used, I would expect such basic functionality to work. Certainly it works fine in IE 6 for static and dynamically created textarea elements (PS I am no fan of Prototype.js, but some very good programers have worked on it and it was widely used, it's still used by Apple).

Answer (score 0):

You should explain more about how you are using the AJAX response, the following works fine in IE 6 with Prototype.js v 1.7.1. I've used DOM and innerHTML to emulate what you might be doing with the AJAX response:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.observe('change', function(e, el) {
    if (el = e.findElement('textarea')) {
        alert(el.value);
    }
});

function addTextarea(el){
  var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
  ta.name = 'ta2';
  el.parentNode.insertBefore(ta, el.nextSibling);
}

function addTextarea2(){
  document.getElementById('s0').innerHTML = '<textarea></textarea>';
}
</script>

<textarea name="answer8158" id="answer8158"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="addTextarea(this);">Add using DOM</button><br>
<button onclick="addTextarea2();">Add using innerHTML</button><span id="s0"></span>
```

If you are programmatically changing the value and expecting a change event to fire, that is entirely different. BTW, I would write the observer as:

```
document.observe('change', function(e) {
    var el = e.findElement('textarea');
    if (el) {
        alert(el.value);
    }
});
```

which is only a few extra characters and a lot clearer.

Comment: This solution still has the same result in IE7 and IE8.  I haven't tried the other versions, but IE7 and IE8 are the main ones I need it working in.